# Property of critical point when the Hessian is degenerate

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $f:{\Bbb R^2}\to{\Bbb R}$ be a function such that
>   $$
> f(x,y)=5x^2+xy^3-3x^2y.
> $$
>   Is $(0,0)$ a local maximum, local minimum or a saddle point?

Calculation shows that $(0,0)$ is a degenerate critical point. One can of course use MATLAB or Mathematic to have a graph to see the property of this point.

- How can I do it in another way?
- To raise the question to a more general setting: what are the usually ways to deal with the degenerate critical points of a smooth multivariable function?

Answer (score 1):

Informally, you only need to look at the function when $x$ and $y$ are small. In that case, the 3rd order element $x^2y$ and the 4th order elements $xy^3$ can be neglected in front of the 2nd order element $5x^2$. So $f(x,y) \approx 5x^2$, which looks like a parabolic cylinder in the $Oy$ direction.

More formally, replace $f$ by the first terms of a Taylor series :
$$ f(x,y) = f(0,0) + \frac {\partial f} {\partial x} x + \frac {\partial f} {\partial y} y + \frac {\partial^2 f} {\partial x^2} x^2 + \frac {\partial^2 f} {\partial x \partial y} x y + \frac {\partial^2 f} {\partial y^2} y^2 +....$$

keeping only the terms of the smallest degree, which gives you an approximation of the function in the neighborhood of $(0,0)$.

In your case, your $f$ is a polynomial, so the Taylor expansion is itself.

Comment: According to your answer, it is a minimum?

Comment: When (x,y)~(0,0), f(x,y)=3x²+O(x³)+O(x²y)+O(xy²)+O(y³). So near (0,0), f(x,y) is positive, and (0,0) is a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

The systematic way to study (critical) points of a function is to cut the function by the tangent plane, which gives a plane curve, and to study the signs.

Because you are on a critical point, the equation of the tangent plane is $z=f(0,0)=0$, and $f$ is above the minimum when $f(x,y)=5x^2+xy^3−3x^2y>0$, and below the minimum when it is negative. By continuity, the sign of $f$ remains constant on the region of the plane cut by the curve $f(x,y)=5x^2+xy^3−3x^2y=0$.

Factoring $f(x,y)=x(5x+y^3−3xy)=0$, we see that the curve is the union of the straight line $x=0$ and a cubic $5x+y^3−3xy=0$. If you plot the cubic, for example by rewriting its equation as $x=\frac {y^3} {3y-5}$, you will find a [Newton trident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_curve) with asymptote $y=5/3$.

What is relevant for the local behavior, is that the cubic pass through the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$, with a tangent in the direction of $Oy$ at this point. So when you turn around the origin $(0,0)$, the function $f(x,y)$ will change sign (a) when you cross the straight line $Oy$ and (b) when you cross the cubic. So, if you could assimilate the cubic to its tangent, the two changes in sing will cancel, and $(0,0)$ would be a minimum.

Now, as pointed out by [@Stefan Smith](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/55689/stefan-smith), the cubic cannot be assimilated to its tangent, so if you take $(x,y)$ with $0<x<x=\frac {y^3} {3y-5}$, you will get $f(x,y)<0$. Therefore, $(0,0)$ is a saddle-point.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

It is pretty easy to show $(0,0)$ is not a local maximum.  Examine the behavior of $f$ along the coordinate axes.  This is always a good idea.

It is harder to show $(0,0)$ is not a local minimum.
For small $|y|$, $|-3x^2 y| << x^2$, so you can pretty much ignore the $-3x^2 y$ term, and choosing $x$ positive and $y=-x^{1/10}$, $xy^3$ is negative with $|xy^3| >> 5x^2$ for small $x$.  So $(0,0)$ is not a local minimum.

If the above is not persuasive, then explicitly, for $x>0$,

$$f(x, -(x^{1/10}))= 5x^2+x(-x^{3/10})+3x^2 x^{1/10}=5x^2+3x^{{21}/{10}}-x^{{13}/{10}}, $$

which is negative for small positive $x$ because $13/10 < 2$ and $13/10 < 21/10$.

I noticed that the middle term in $f(x,y)$ had $x$ instead of $x^2$ and that $x$ was multiplied by $y^3$, with $y$ free to approach zero at any rate one pleases. So by setting $y$ equal to an appropriate power of $x$, you can make $f(x,y)$ negative for certain small $x$ and $y$.

I don't know if there is a systematic procedure for this kind of problem.  Perhaps using higher-order derivatives would help?

Comment: I don't see why @user1938185's answer contradicts your argument that $(0,0)$ is not a local minimum.

Comment: @Goku : the statement that the fourth order element $x y^3$ can be neglected in favor of the second order element $5x^2$ is false, because you can choose $y$ large enough so that $|xy^3| > 5x^2$.  I did exactly that in my answer (which I just edited to make it clearer).

Comment: I agree with @Stefan, I was too quick. To tackle the question in a systematic way, cut the curve with the plane z=f(0,0)=0 and look the signs. As the answer involves a cubic, it may be wise I go back to the markup level.