# Finding $\max$ and min of function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have a problem with following assignment. I need to find critical points of function $$f (x,y)=x^{3}y-3x^{2}y+y^2$$ and determine whether function has min/max or not.
$$Df=[3x^{2}y-6xy,x^3-3x^2+2y]$$
Critical points are:$(0,0)(3,0)(2,2)$ and 
$$D^2f=\begin{pmatrix}6xy-6y &3x^2-6x\\3x^2-6x&2\end{pmatrix}$$
For $(2,2)$ we get positive definite matrix so it has $\min$ in $(2,2)$.
For the other two I have no idea how to examine them. Because matrix is: 
$$\begin{vmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{vmatrix}\quad \text{ and } \quad \begin{vmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 9\end{vmatrix}$$
I will be very glad for help.

Comment: $D^2f(3,0)=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 9 \\
9 & 2 \end{array} \right)$ there is a positive and a negative eigen value therefore this is not an extrema

Answer (score 1):

Use the  characteristic  polynomial of the Hessian matrix if the roots(eigenvalues) for the polynomial are positive it is positive definite (min) if they are all negative  it is negative definite(max)   if they are negative and positive then its indefinite(saddle point).

Comment: I guess it is not the case here. One root is 0 other 2 so we can't use that statment.

Comment: you can inspect your function then to see what happens to the point  that your determinant is zero.maybe factorization.But you have to inspect if no criterions are usefull .Also check your calculations .

Comment: For (3.0) your calculations are wrong. $$D^2f(3,0)=\begin{pmatrix}0&9\\9&2\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: You are right so,  for (3,0) we have saddle point. How to deal with (0,0) then? I tried to factorize it but with no luck.

Comment: obviously it is not a total max or min. So you have to figure out what happens to that point locally. so try  numerical or in really small areas to see what happens to f .that is what i would do.Also check the theory  for Degenerate critical points .I am currently studying something related too and have not looked into the theory of degenerate critical points.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622417/property-of-critical-point-when-the-hessian-is-degenerate check this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint for how to deal with the point $(0,0)$:

Since the Hessian is only semidefinite, the usual method breaks down, so you'll have to use your imagination and come up with some custom-made method for this particular problem.

The eigenvector with the zero eigenvalue is $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, and this is the direction where the quadratic form in the Taylor expansion leaves a "hole" where higher-order terms may influence what happens. So a good idea is to look in the $x$ direction.

First we try $f(x,0)$, but that's identically zero, which doesn't lead to any conclusion (other than that *if* there is a local extremum, it can't be *strict*).

But what happens if you look at $f(x,x^3)$? (I.e., you look along the curve $y=x^3$, which is tangential to the $x$ axis at the origin.)